# Error message "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" is shown when run java on command line

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, cmd, classpath

I am trying to run the java program on command line but this message is shown:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

Then I have searched a few hours and most solutions are about checking the

1. Java version,
2. importing the JDBC jar and
3. editing the classpath

For 1, I checked the java version I am using is 1.8

So for 2, I have  downloaded the sqljdbc41.jar , put the jar into a lib folder, and run the command with:

```
java -cp C://Testing/lib/* -classpath . sampleJava
```

For 3, I have edited the classpath to C://Testing/lib/sqljdbc41.jar

Anyone knows do I miss something so that the same error message still shows?

Below is the sample program I run:

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class sampleJava {
  int x = 5;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    sampleJava myObj = new sampleJava();
    try {
    Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Got an exception! ");
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            System.err.println(e);
            System.out.println(e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    finally {           
                System.out.println("Done");
        }
    System.out.println(myObj.x);
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried with backslash characters in your classpath? i.e.:  `C:\Testing\lib\sqljdbc41.jar`?

Comment: Thanks. I have make a typo above that I was actually using C:\Testing\lib\sqljdbc41.jar

Comment: Not related to your problem, but sqljdbc41 is for Java 7, and is pretty old. For a more recent driver go to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/download-microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help

```
java -cp C:/Testing/lib/*; sampleJava
```

or

```
java -cp C:/Testing/lib/sqljdbc41.jar; sampleJava
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. You saved my day. Just noticed that I make a stupid mistake that I forget the semi-colon after the word jar.

Comment: @metallic I think the problem was your use of `//` instead of `/`, not the semi-colon, which separates elements on the classpath and doesn't actually belong at the end of the classpath.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel it does not work for me without the semi-colon on my windows 10 machine using cmd. It gives me the error - "Could not find or load main class sampleJava"

Comment: Interesting, it seems that an empty classpath segment is equivalent to `.` (so `-cp C:/Testing/lib/sqljdbc41.jar;.` and `C:/Testing/lib/sqljdbc41.jar;` are equivalent; I did not know that.